# JSON type NSMutableDictionary cannot be converted to .sdp must not be null

Tags: javascript, json, firebase, react-native, webrtc

Am new to webRTC and am trying to create a react native app with video calling functionality using this tutorial here as an example to follow https://dipanshkhandelwal.medium.com/video-calling-using-firebase-and-webrtc-14cc2d4afceb

However i keep getting this error on iOS and on android the app just closes once i try to join a call. The error i get on iOS says:

```
JSON value '{
}' of type NSMutableDictionary cannot be converted to .sdp must not be null

+[RCTConvert(WebRTC) RTCSessionDescription:]
    RCTConvert+WebRTC.m:22
__41-[RCTModuleMethod processMethodSignature]_block_invoke_16
-[RCTModuleMethod invokeWithBridge:module:arguments:]
facebook::react::invokeInner(RCTBridge*, RCTModuleData*, unsigned int, folly::dynamic const&, int, (anonymous namespace)::SchedulingContext)
facebook::react::RCTNativeModule::invoke(unsigned int, folly::dynamic&&, int)::$_0::operator()() const
invocation function for block in facebook::react::RCTNativeModule::invoke(unsigned int, folly::dynamic&&, int)
_dispatch_call_block_and_release
_dispatch_client_callout
_dispatch_lane_serial_drain
_dispatch_lane_invoke
_dispatch_workloop_worker_thread
_pthread_wqthread
start_wqthread
```

in metro this comes up as an error:

```
Possible Unhandled Promise Rejection (id: 0):
Object {
  "message": "SessionDescription is NULL.",
  "name": "SetRemoteDescriptionFailed",
}
```

A sample of the offer created in firstore in the respective room is below. Am suspecting the sdp might be invalid or something.

_sdp:

```
v=0o=- 765269967391877801 2 IN IP4 127.0.0.1s=-t=0 0a=group:BUNDLE audio videoa=msid-semantic: WMS a3a6a14c-980f-4052-a881-e53290c2e9a8m=video 100c=IN IP4 0.0.0.0a=rtcp:9 IN IP4 0.0.0.0a=ice-ufrag:qfEea=ice-pwd:aMtS7ouM3ykOCV6z7jx0hhlSa=ice-options:trickle renominationa=fingerprint:sha-256 01:13:79:2E:BA:E3:67:9A:77:66:90:00:D7:62:BA:31:2C:48:FC:EB:8C:21:22:7E:5B:9D:0E:71:82:5F:63:5Aa=setup:actpassa=mid:audioa=extmap:1 urn:ietf:params:rtp-hdrext:ssrc-audio-levela=extmap:2 http://www.webrtc.org/experiments/rtp-hdrext/abs-send-timea=extmap:3 http://www.ietf.org/id/draft-holmer-rmcat-transport-wide-cc-extensions-01a=sendrecva=rtcp-muxa=rtpmap:111 opus/48000/2a=rtcp-fb:111 transport-cca=fmtp:111 minptime=10;useinbandfec=1a=rtpmap:103 ISAC/16000a=rtpmap:9 G722/8000a=rtpmap:102 ILBC/8000a=rtpmap:0 PCMU/8000a=rtpmap:8 PCMA/8000a=rtpmap:105 CN/16000a=rtpmap:13 CN/8000a=rtpmap:110 telephone-event/48000a=rtpmap:113 telephone-event/16000a=rtpmap:126 telephone-event/8000a=ssrc:866776128 cname:OXEDL0qxAsrhPmB7a=ssrc:866776128 msid:a3a6a14c-980f-4052-a881-e53290c2e9a8 256a9ac0-8163-45b5-ae52-0ece88651c51a=ssrc:866776128 mslabel:a3a6a14c-980f-4052-a881-e53290c2e9a8a=ssrc:866776128 label:256a9ac0-8163-45b5-ae52-0ece88651c51m=video 9 UDP/TLS/RTP/SAVPF 96 97 98 99 100 101 127c=IN IP4 0.0.0.0a=rtcp:9 IN IP4 0.0.0.0a=ice-ufrag:qfEea=ice-pwd:aMtS7ouM3ykOCV6z7jx0hhlSa=ice-options:trickle renominationa=fingerprint:sha-256 01:13:79:2E:BA:E3:67:9A:77:66:90:00:D7:62:BA:31:2C:48:FC:EB:8C:21:22:7E:5B:9D:0E:71:82:5F:63:5Aa=setup:actpassa=mid:videoa=extmap:14 urn:ietf:params:rtp-hdrext:toffseta=extmap:2 http://www.webrtc.org/experiments/rtp-hdrext/abs-send-timea=extmap:13 urn:3gpp:video-orientationa=extmap:3 http://www.ietf.org/id/draft-holmer-rmcat-transport-wide-cc-extensions-01a=extmap:5 http://www.webrtc.org/experiments/rtp-hdrext/playout-delaya=extmap:6 http://www.webrtc.org/experiments/rtp-hdrext/video-content-typea=extmap:7 http://www.webrtc.org/experiments/rtp-hdrext/video-timinga=extmap:8 http://www.webrtc.org/experiments/rtp-hdrext/color-spacea=sendrecva=rtcp-muxa=rtcp-rsizea=rtpmap:96 VP8/90000a=rtcp-fb:96 goog-remba=rtcp-fb:96 transport-cca=rtcp-fb:96 ccm fira=rtcp-fb:96 nacka=rtcp-fb:96 nack plia=rtpmap:97 rtx/90000a=fmtp:97 apt=96a=rtpmap:98 VP9/90000a=rtcp-fb:98 goog-remba=rtcp-fb:98 transport-cca=rtcp-fb:98 ccm fira=rtcp-fb:98 nacka=rtcp-fb:98 nack plia=rtpmap:99 rtx/90000a=fmtp:99 apt=98a=rtpmap:100 red/90000a=rtpmap:101 rtx/90000a=fmtp:101 apt=100a=rtpmap:127 ulpfec/90000a=ssrc-group:FID 2850853975 3259115858a=ssrc:2850853975 cname:OXEDL0qxAsrhPmB7a=ssrc:2850853975 msid:a3a6a14c-980f-4052-a881-e53290c2e9a8 3f3952f6-cd3d-4d3e-a2dc-81eda77cf516a=ssrc:2850853975 mslabel:a3a6a14c-980f-4052-a881-e53290c2e9a8a=ssrc:2850853975 label:3f3952f6-cd3d-4d3e-a2dc-81eda77cf516a=ssrc:3259115858 cname:OXEDL0qxAsrhPmB7a=ssrc:3259115858 msid:a3a6a14c-980f-4052-a881-e53290c2e9a8 3f3952f6-cd3d-4d3e-a2dc-81eda77cf516a=ssrc:3259115858 mslabel:a3a6a14c-980f-4052-a881-e53290c2e9a8a=ssrc:3259115858 label:3f3952f6-cd3d-4d3e-a2dc-81eda77cf516
```

Tried everything but can't seem to figure it out. The callee collection also never gets created in the respective rooms in firestore database. Any help with this would be appreciated.

Comment: Can anyone help with this please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess you are trying to use firebase as a signalling medium and want to use react-native-webrtc for the video calling.

Here is the sample code I have for the same solution with the latest libraries and react-native version.

[Firebase Installation React Native.](https://rnfirebase.io/#installation)

Just set up ios and android using this above link and then use the below code for reference.

```
import React, {useEffect, useState} from 'react';

import {Modal, TextInput, ToastAndroid, View} from 'react-native';
import {ColoredButton} from '../app/common/commonViews';
import {
  mediaDevices,
  MediaStream,
  RTCIceCandidate,
  RTCPeerConnection,
  RTCSessionDescription,
  RTCView,
} from 'react-native-webrtc';

import firestore from '@react-native-firebase/firestore';

const Home = () => {
  const [localStream, setLocalStream] = useState(null);
  const [remoteStream, setRemoteStream] = useState(new MediaStream());
  const [modalVisible, setModalVisible] = useState(false);
  const [roomName, setRoomName] = useState('2277');
  let peerConnection;

  const configuration = {
    iceServers: [
      {urls: 'stun:stun.services.mozilla.com'},
      {urls: 'stun:stun.l.google.com:19302'},
    ],
  };
  let isFront = true;

  useEffect(() => {
    mediaDevices.enumerateDevices().then((sourceInfos) => {
      console.log(sourceInfos);
      let videoSourceId;
      for (let i = 0; i < sourceInfos.length; i++) {
        const sourceInfo = sourceInfos[i];
        if (
          sourceInfo.kind == 'videoinput' &&
          sourceInfo.facing == (isFront ? 'front' : 'environment')
        ) {
          videoSourceId = sourceInfo.deviceId;
        }
      }
      mediaDevices
        .getUserMedia({
          audio: true,
          video: {
            width: 640,
            height: 480,
            frameRate: 30,
            facingMode: isFront ? 'user' : 'environment',
            deviceId: videoSourceId,
          },
        })
        .then((stream) => {
          setLocalStream(stream);
          // Got stream!
        })
        .catch((error) => {
          // Log error
        });
    });
  }, [isFront]);

  async function createRoom() {
    const roomRef = firestore().collection('rooms').doc(roomName);
    console.log(roomRef);
    console.log('Create PeerConnection with configuration: ', configuration);
    peerConnection = new RTCPeerConnection(configuration);

    peerConnection.addStream(localStream);

    // Code for collecting ICE candidates below
    const callerCandidatesCollection = roomRef.collection('callerCandidates');

    // Code for collecting ICE candidates above

    peerConnection.onicecandidate = function (event) {
      if (!event.candidate) {
        console.log('Got final candidate!');
        return;
      }
      console.log('Got candidate: ', event.candidate);
      callerCandidatesCollection.add(event.candidate.toJSON());
    };

    peerConnection.onicegatheringstatechange = () => {
      console.log(
        `ICE gathering state changed: ${peerConnection.iceGatheringState}`,
      );
    };

    peerConnection.onconnectionstatechange = () => {
      console.log(`Connection state change: ${peerConnection.connectionState}`);
    };

    peerConnection.onsignalingstatechange = () => {
      console.log(`Signaling state change: ${peerConnection.signalingState}`);
    };

    peerConnection.oniceconnectionstatechange = () => {
      console.log(
        `ICE connection state change: ${peerConnection.iceConnectionState}`,
      );
    };

    console.log('Created offer:', offer);

    // Code for creating a room below
    const offer = await peerConnection.createOffer();
    await peerConnection.setLocalDescription(offer);

    const roomWithOffer = {
      offer: {
        type: offer.type,
        sdp: offer.sdp,
      },
    };
    await roomRef.set(roomWithOffer);
    console.log(`New room created with SDP offer. Room ID: ${roomRef.id}`);
    ToastAndroid.show(
      `New room created with SDP offer. Room ID: ${roomRef.id}`,
      ToastAndroid.SHORT,
    );
    // Code for creating a room above

    peerConnection.onaddstream = (event) => {
      setRemoteStream(event.stream);
    };

    // Listening for remote session description below
    roomRef.onSnapshot(async (snapshot) => {
      const data = snapshot.data();
      if (!peerConnection.currentRemoteDescription && data && data.answer) {
        console.log('Got remote description: ', data.answer);
        const rtcSessionDescription = new RTCSessionDescription(data.answer);
        await peerConnection.setRemoteDescription(rtcSessionDescription);
      }
    });
    // Listening for remote session description above

    // Listen for remote ICE candidates below
    roomRef.collection('calleeCandidates').onSnapshot((snapshot) => {
      snapshot.docChanges().forEach(async (change) => {
        if (change.type === 'added') {
          let data = change.doc.data();
          console.log(`Got new remote ICE candidate: ${JSON.stringify(data)}`);
          await peerConnection.addIceCandidate(new RTCIceCandidate(data));
        }
      });
    });
    // Listen for remote ICE candidates above
  }

  async function joinRoomById(roomId) {
    const roomRef = firestore().collection('rooms').doc(`${roomId}`);
    const roomSnapshot = await roomRef.get({
      source: 'server',
    });
    console.log('Got room:', roomSnapshot.exists);

    if (roomSnapshot.exists) {
      console.log('Create PeerConnection with configuration: ', configuration);
      peerConnection = new RTCPeerConnection(configuration);
      peerConnection.addStream(localStream);

      // Code for collecting ICE candidates below
      const calleeCandidatesCollection = roomRef.collection('calleeCandidates');
      peerConnection.onicecandidate = function (event) {
        if (!event.candidate) {
          console.log('Got final candidate!');
          return;
        }
        console.log('Got candidate: ', event.candidate);
        calleeCandidatesCollection.add(event.candidate.toJSON());
      };

      peerConnection.onicegatheringstatechange = () => {
        console.log(
          `ICE gathering state changed: ${peerConnection.iceGatheringState}`,
        );
      };

      peerConnection.onconnectionstatechange = () => {
        console.log(
          `Connection state change: ${peerConnection.connectionState}`,
        );
      };

      peerConnection.onsignalingstatechange = () => {
        console.log(`Signaling state change: ${peerConnection.signalingState}`);
      };

      peerConnection.oniceconnectionstatechange = () => {
        console.log(
          `ICE connection state change: ${peerConnection.iceConnectionState}`,
        );
      };

      // Code for collecting ICE candidates above

      peerConnection.onaddstream = (event) => {
        setRemoteStream(event.stream);
      };

      // Code for creating SDP answer below
      const offer = roomSnapshot.data().offer;
      console.log('Got offer:', offer);
      await peerConnection.setRemoteDescription(
        new RTCSessionDescription(offer),
      );
      const answer = await peerConnection.createAnswer();
      console.log('Created answer:', answer);
      await peerConnection.setLocalDescription(answer);

      const roomWithAnswer = {
        answer: {
          type: answer.type,
          sdp: answer.sdp,
        },
      };
      await roomRef.update(roomWithAnswer);
      // Code for creating SDP answer above

      // Listening for remote ICE candidates below
      roomRef.collection('callerCandidates').onSnapshot((snapshot) => {
        snapshot.docChanges().forEach(async (change) => {
          if (change.type === 'added') {
            let data = change.doc.data();
            console.log(
              `Got new remote ICE candidate: ${JSON.stringify(data)}`,
            );
            await peerConnection.addIceCandidate(new RTCIceCandidate(data));
          }
        });
      });
      // Listening for remote ICE candidates above
    }
  }

  return (
    <View style={{flex: 1}}>
      <Modal
        visible={modalVisible}
        transparent={true}
        style={{justifyContent: 'center'}}>
        <View
          style={{
            height: 100,
            padding: 20,
            width: '80%',
            alignSelf: 'center',
            justifyContent: 'center',
            backgroundColor: 'white',
          }}>
          <TextInput
            value={roomName}
            onChangeText={(text) => {
              setRoomName(text);
            }}
            placeholder={'Enter text'}
          />
          <View
            style={{
              flexDirection: 'row',
              justifyContent: 'space-evenly',
            }}>
            <ColoredButton
              title="close"
              onPress={() => {
                setModalVisible(!modalVisible);
              }}
            />
            <ColoredButton
              title="create"
              onPress={() => {
                setModalVisible(!modalVisible);
              }}
            />
            <ColoredButton
              title="join"
              onPress={() => {
                setModalVisible(!modalVisible);
              }}
            />
          </View>
        </View>
      </Modal>
      <RTCView
        streamURL={localStream ? localStream.toURL() : null}
        style={{flex: 1, margin: 20, backgroundColor: 'black'}}
      />
      <RTCView
        style={{
          flex: 1,
          marginLeft: 20,
          marginRight: 20,
          backgroundColor: 'black',
        }}
        streamURL={remoteStream ? remoteStream.toURL() : null}
      />
      <TextInput value={roomName} onChangeText={setRoomName} />
      <View
        style={{
          flexDirection: 'row',
          justifyContent: 'space-evenly',
          width: '100%',
          padding: 20,
        }}>
        <ColoredButton
          title="Create"
          onPress={() => {
            createRoom().then((r) => {});
          }}
        />
        <ColoredButton
          title="Join"
          onPress={() => {
            joinRoomById(roomName).then((r) => {});
          }}
        />
      </View>
    </View>
  );
};

export default Home;
```

Comment: Thank you so much for this. You are a lifesaver. Thank you!!!